# VueJS passing object to root component function

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am using VueJS in my HTML template for an app.
Button click passes the object of an component to its root component like so:

```
<button v-on:click="$root.savePlan(dataObj)"></button>
```

dataObj is passed as props like so:

```
<plan-single-job :dataObj="dataObj"/>
```

and button is inside the "plan-single-job" component. The component also has one data parameter on its own, called "edit_mode", which is boolean type.

In my root component, I have a function declaration "savePlan(obj)". When the button in "plan-single-job" is pressed, the method savePlan in root is called, and the object dataObj is passed.

My question is, is there a way to access component "plan-single-job" data from "dataObj" object?

Save plan:

```
savePlan: function(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
  console.log(obj.edit_mode); // ?
}
```

Plan-single-job component

```
Vue.component('plan-single-job',{
  template: "#plan-single-job",
  props: {
    dataObj: {
      type: Object,
      default: {},  
    },
  },
  data: function(){
    return{
      edit_mode: false,
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Did you tried with `ref`?

Comment: I have a for loop in root component for "plan-single-job" so the ref should change for everycomponent called.

Comment: Please avoid using unrelated tags next time ...

Answer (score 0):

You should use a local method instead of referencing the root method int he template.

**Template:**

```
<button v-on:click="localMethod"></button>
```

**Script:**

```
Vue.component('plan-single-job',{
  template: "#plan-single-job",
  props: {
    dataObj: {
      type: Object,
      default: {},
    },
  },
  data: function(){
    return{
      edit_mode: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    localMethod: function () {
      this.$root.savePlan(this.dataObj, {
        edit_mode: edit_mode
      })
    }
  }
})
```

You could then pass any initial data to the `$root` method after the `dataObj`